# OWL-S and semantic similarity of web services

Tags: web-services, wsdl, semantics, matching, owl

I am currently dealing with semantic descriptions of web services, OWL-S more specifically. I'm not manually writing the annotations, I use this tool.

My point is not the annotations per se, but to know how close 2 web services are. So my idea was to try and compare their respective OWL-S descriptions.

What I'm looking for is maybe a matcher, an API (Java or Python) that would allow me to match two .owl files.

**UPDATE** : This is just my idea. If you can suggest something else that serves the same purpose you are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [LogMap](https://code.google.com/p/logmap-matcher/), it's a framework for ontology matching. You can try it from the [web interface](http://csu6325.cs.ox.ac.uk/). In case of problem you can contact directly the authors of the tool too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The thing is, I don't need to match whole ontologies, but just the semantic annotations (where these onotologies are used). Could I use this tool to do that ?

Comment: OK, so if I understood correctly, you have: one ontology O, a web service A and a web service B that have both been annotated with classes from O. Given the WS A you would like to know how close is B in regards to O. It's called semantic similarity. I am not aware of any tool doing this, yet you could look at http://www.ganjisaffar.com/papers/2006-WI.pdf and https://code.google.com/p/owltools/wiki/OwlSim as starting points. It's a common measure in biology, yet there are no widely accepted definition and methodology for it, and unfortunately no lib for the OWL-S as far as I know.

Comment: if interested, contact the authors of the resources, they should reply to you and know probably more than I do.